# Vector field with numpy and a curve

Tags: numpy, vector

I'm trying to create a vector field and some curve, I've created a vector field as shown

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3,3,.35),np.arange(-3,3,.35))
u = x
v = y


plt.quiver(x, y, u, v,  color = 'black')

plt.show()
```

But I want to add the curve $y=x^2$ in the same plot, how could I do that?

I've tryeid to add plt.plot and the curve but the result is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to keep the y-axis limit as was in the mesh grid. `plt.ylim` is helpful in that case

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3, 3, .35), np.arange(-3, 3, .35))
u = x
v = y

plt.quiver(x, y, u, v,  color = 'black')

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
ylim = plt.ylim()
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.ylim(ylim)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]